# How can I find a natural border polygon of a set of arbitrarily placed non-overlapping rectangles?

Tags: geometry, 2d, polygon

Given a set of arbitrarily placed, non-overlapping rectangles; how could I find a polygon that represents a natural border around the points that make up the rectangles?  To illustrate:[image]

How can I find either the green or blue line?  I have tried, but not succeeded, with the following:

- Walking using pathfinding. I struggled to find a heuristic that made sense.
- Walking using distance threshold and choosing next based on angle about the vector of the previous two points (e.g. always turn right).  This kinda worked but had a lot of weird edge cases that didn't.
- Procedurally building up the polygon starting with an initial diamond of the left, top, right and bottom most points.  The idea was to detect if a point was inside the polgyon already, in which case ignore it, but when I needed to insert I didn't know how to determine the insert position.

I'm unsure if I'm missing something obvious or if this is actually a harder problem than I initially expected.

Comment: How about finding the Convex Hull of all vertices? Or even a Delaunay triangulation. Once you have it, you can make some refinements, like replacing an edge in the hull with two edges in rectangles. Be aware of such refinements may be good only depending of the boxes setting.

Comment: Hi - thanks... convex hull is what I'm looking for (I just didn't know the name of it) and I have actually managed to do it now by using the technique in point 3 above.  I order the points using furthers from the polygon center first, cull any contained and then find the nearest line segment to the next point at in the set and insert between the points of that segment.  I'm not sure if this is efficient but it does work.  I will post it as the answer I nobody else has a better technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a heuristic. Compute the hull *H*<sub>1</sub> of
the rectangles. Now compute the hull *H*<sub>2</sub>
of the rectangle corners not on *H*<sub>1</sub>.
So now you have two nested convex hulls.
Consider moving an edge *e* of *H*<sub>1</sub> to
a vertex *v* of *H*<sub>2</sub>.
Some such moves can be excluded because the two new
edges cross a rectangle. Choose to accept the smallest
altitudes of the triangle formed by *e* and *v*,
as suggested in the image below.

---

[image: HullOnion]

---